# Ordered numbered nested list in TCPDF

Tags: html, css, html-lists, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to create PDF docuemnts from HTML Code and I'm creating nested lists which should be displayed there. But instead of

1. point 1
2. point 2

   1. subpoint of point 2
   2. subpoint of point 2

I need something like

1. point 1
2. point 2

2.1. subpoint of point 2

2.2 subpoint of point 2

In the normal HTML, I managed to do this with css `counters`, so actually this:

```
<style>
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
</style>
```

is all I needed, to get it working (although there are some issues, but in general its working). In TCPDF, I get no error or something, but also, the list ist not styled. I also tried to set `LI` to `color:green;`, but this also didn't work.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: I have been stuck at the same problem as you for weeks. I have tried some TCPDF's functions like `$pdf->setLIsymbol('#');` but nothing changed.

Comment: To set the color, you can try: `ol li {list-style-type:decimal;color:green;}`